# Connecting Samsung Android 8.0 phone to Kubuntu 14.04 via USB

Tags: usb, kubuntu, android, mtp

I am trying to connect a brand new **Samsung Galaxy S7** phone with **Android 8.0** to my **Kubuntu 14.04 computer** via USB.

When I connect the device, it **appears normally on the device notifier** of my computer. I check `SAMSUNG_Android` -> `Open with File Manager`, like I did with my old Android 5.0 device (which was always unstable, but worked). At the same time, a notification on the device says `Android system: Transferring media files via USB`.

A dialog says `No Storages found. Maybe you need to unlock your device?` on the computer, while the device is not locked. At the same time, a dialog appears on the device, saying `Allow access to phone data? The connected device will be able to access data on this phone. DENY/ALLOW`. I check `ALLOW` but the file manager just shows an empty folder and refreshing does not help. No matter how many times I repeat, the behavior is always the same, and **I never get to access any data**.

Following advice on Android forums, I enable `Developer options` and `USB debugging` on the phone, while `USB Configuration` is `MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)` by default.

On the computer, I try installing and using `mtpfs` and `jmtpfs`, with no success. My understanding is that they both use `libmtp` underneath. I have **`libmtp 1.1.6`** and `mtp-detect` says

```
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 5, dev 8
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:1
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02fe: PTP: Protocol error, data expected
USB low-level info:
   bcdUSB: 512
   bDeviceClass: 0
   bDeviceSubClass: 0
   bDeviceProtocol: 0
   idVendor: 04e8
   idProduct: 6860
   IN endpoint maxpacket: 512 bytes
   OUT endpoint maxpacket: 512 bytes
   Raw device info:
      Bus location: 5
      Device number: 8
      Device entry info:
         Vendor: Samsung
         Vendor id: 0x04e8
         Product: Galaxy models (MTP)
         Vendor id: 0x6860
         Device flags: 0x48000207
```

followed by a bunch of additional information.

I try connecting the phone to a **Windows 7 computer**, and it **works perfectly**.

I then try the same to a **Windows 7 virtual machine** inside my Kubuntu 14.04 host, but unfortunately no USB device is seen.

Then, I try a **Kubuntu 18.04 virtual machine** inside the same Kubuntu 14.04 host. This can see the USB device, but upon accessing with File Manager as above, a dialog on the computer says `The process for the mtp protocol died unexpectedly` while nothing appears on the device. Such message still appears randomly with my old Android 5.0 phone on my Kubuntu 14.04 computer, but eventually it works; while here the failure is consistent. `mtp-detect` now says

```
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 4
Attempting to connect device(s)
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not open session! (Return code 8194)
  Try to reset the device.
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Googling that message, I cannot find anything helpful.

Finally, I install the latest **`libmtp 1.1.15`** from source on my Kubuntu 14.04. Nothing changes in the File Manager access, while `mtp-detect` similarly says

```
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.15

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 5, dev 16
Attempting to connect device(s)
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not open session! (Return code 8194)
  Try to reset the device.
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

and the device shows the familiar `ALLOW/DENY` dialog.

I remember trying **another Samsung Android** phone (6.0 or 7.0 I think) to **another Kubuntu 14.04** computer with the same `No Storages found` and `ALLOW/DENY` behavior, but I didn't care much at the time because that was not my phone.

I have lost countless hours trying other workarounds with no success. I cannot change my operating system, at least not now. It's still supported for another six months, while the new system does not appear to work any better. I cannot change the phone either, but not being able to transfer files via USB makes it useless.

Such things should really work out of the box, right?

Comment: Have you ried Kubuntu 18.04 from USB? In case it can see Android files, it might be a strong incentive to move on.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks. I had tried in the past and it wouldn't boot. I will try again, but the fact that it fails from virtualbox is not a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/udev/rules.d` for a file named `xx-android.rules`. I believe I manually created mine but it was years ago. Possibly on 14.04 as you're running. My android rules file is named `51-android.rules`.

If this file exists, open it to determine if your specific device is included. I'm willing to bet it isn't.

If not,

```
`sudo <your_favorite_editor> /etc/udev/rules.d/xx-android.rules`
```

and add the following rule

```
`ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"`
```

If you don't have an xx-android.rules file, let me know and I'll tell you how to create one.

Just for GP, here's a template for an android rules files

```
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="android_usb_rules_end"
LABEL="android_usb_rules_begin"

ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", SYMINK+="libmtp-%k", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"

LABEL="android_usb_rules_end"
```

The following requires root permissions...
Place the template in /etc/udev/rules.d/. Save as xx-android.rules where 'xx' is a number between 10 and 99. IE; 51-android.rules

Log out of your session and log back in. I recommend rebooting instead.

Comment: Thanks. One of the workarounds I tried was like that and failed, but I don't recall details now. There is no such file. How do I create it and what should `xx` be? By the way, I do have the rule `ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"` in `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`, which defines `Samsung Galaxy models (MTP)` as listed in my question.

Comment: The XX can be any number between 10 and 99, if memory serves. The higher the number the higher the priority. My file is "51-android.rules" but mine also contains entries for over 100 devices. You're good if you have another file with the same rule(s) however. I think your problem is the MODE="660". And I don't think the GROUP item is needed either. Try changing MODE="660" to MODE="666". Or remove it all together. You'll need to sudo that file to edit it. None of the Samsung entries in my file contain MODE or GROUP.

Comment: I did that (MODE="666", also removing the GROUP), followed by `sudo service udev restart`. Without reboot, the error messages are slightly different now, but it still fails. It's weird because there are hundreds of rules in this file, all with "660".

Comment: Try a custom rules files, like I posted in my answer. I've never had any issues unless I've plugged in a device that wasn't in the rules files. Give it a LOWER number than your 69-libmtp.rules file. I was backwards in my explanation about the numbers.

Comment: After logging out and back in, I observe the behavior has now changed from `No Storages found` and `ALLOW/DENY` to `The process for the mtp protocol died unexpectedly`, as in 18.04. This must be the new `libmtp` in effect.

Comment: Tried the custom file as you say. Log out/in, no reboot. Still the same. Device is still referred to as `Samsung Galaxy models (MTP)` by `mtp-detect`. I am not sure if the custom rule is in effect.

Comment: I hate to admit it but I'm at a loss...